# Can't access an mp3 file in perl

Tags: perl, mp3

I am new to perl and was messing around with mp3 files using this program, but it doesn't seem to work.
So I want to access this file in my music folder and print it out, but whenever I'm running the script I'm getting the error:

> Can't call method `get_tags` on an `undefined` value at line 5.

I know it's probably something basic but I couldn't find it on google. Thanks in advance

```
use 5.0.10;
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use MP3::Tag;
$mp3=MP3::Tag->new("C:\Users\plank223\Music\Ellie Goulding - Bright Lights (Deluxe Edition).mp3");
$mp3->get_tags();
if (exists $mp3->{ID3v1}) {
    print "Filename: $filename\n";
    print "Artist: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->artist."\n";
    print "Title: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->title . "\n";
    print "Album: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->album . "\n";
    print "Year: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->year . "\n";
    print "Genre: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->genre . "\n";
} else {
    print "Oi, no data here";
}
$mp3->close();
```

Comment: You're not checking for an error condition in this line: `$mp3=MP3::Tag->new("C:\Users\plank223\Music\Ellie Goulding - Bright Lights (Deluxe Edition).mp3");`. What is the value of $mp3 if there is an error? Is it undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your program:

You are using double quotes `"` and backslashes in your Windows paths. Perl thinks you are trying to escape characters in the path with the backslash `\`. If you had read the complete error message, you would have seen something like this.

> Unrecognized escape \m passed through at F:\scratch3.pl line 10.
>   Unrecognized escape \D passed through at F:\scratch3.pl line 10.
>   Unrecognized escape \D passed through at F:\scratch3.pl line 10.
>   Unrecognized escape \D passed through at F:\scratch3.pl line 10.

That's Perl complaining about the escaped parts of the path. These error messages even show up without `use strict`. **Always read the full error messages, not just the bottom one**.

You can fix that by simply using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` for the path.

This is the reason why `MP3::Tag->new` fails. It will return `undef`, and you will subsequently call the `get_tags` method on an undefined value, as the last error message says.

After that, inside the loop, there is another mistake. You are using `$filename`, which you have not declared.

A working version of your program might look like this.

```
use MP3::Tag;
use strict;
use warnings;

# single quotes here!
my $filename = 
    'C:\Users\plank223\Music\Ellie Goulding - Bright Lights (Deluxe Edition).mp3'; 
my $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($filename);
$mp3->get_tags;

if ( exists $mp3->{ID3v1} ) {
    print "Filename: $filename\n";
    print "Artist: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->artist . "\n";
    print "Title: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->title . "\n";
    print "Album: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->album . "\n";
    print "Year: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->year . "\n";
    print "Genre: " . $mp3->{ID3v1}->genre . "\n";
}
else {
    print "Oi, no data here";
}
$mp3->close;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't really work out. Appreciate it, man.

Comment: @Hadi just saying _it didn't really work out_ is not very helpful. From that, I cannot determine **why** it didn't. Instead, you should supply an error message, or explain how the program behaved now.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I messed up between your answer and the other one. Your advice worked fine and the code ran perfectly. Thank you a lot, and yeah I'll have to write the other guy what errors his code gave.

Comment: @Hadi the advice in Otterbein's answer is solid, but it's not a solution, just debugging help. I would have done the exact same thing they said, but in this case, I was already pretty sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

At the first look your code seems to be correct.
What you can try:

My recommendation to use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Testing the ->new():

```
$mp3=MP3::Tag->new('file.mp3') or die "Can't open file $!";
#if it fails, it prints the message. $! is the error string.
```

looking at the $mp3 itself with Data::Dumper:

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper($mp3);
```

I hope this helps a little bit further!

Comment: Yeah, it kept telling me that I can't open the file, so I tried another one and corrected some stuff using the other guy's answer and it worked. Thanks for the answer, it helped me see what's wrong in the code.